# Run app to embedded jboss server using maven

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I create the simple rest server application using resteasy and maven as build tool by this post http://buraktas.com/resteasy-example-without-using-a-web-xml/. Or it is possible to run created war to the embedded jboss server using maven? I want implement this scenario: 1. I push my project to git hub with source files and pom.xml 2. User clone repo and use maven to build and run app. 3. Go to browser `http://localhost:8080/rest-helloworld/helloworld` and get hello msg.

pom.xml <- now need `mvn clean install` to prepare .war and need copy paste to the application server. I want skip this step.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>buraktas.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-helloworld</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>rest-helloworld</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <warName>rest-helloworld</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Maven JBoss Plugin](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/maven-tutorials/jboss-maven/maven-jboss-as-7-plugin-tutorial) to perform start/stop and deploy/undeploy tasks using Maven.